# Show that the array is infinitesimal

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

> Suppose that $\left\{X_{n,j} : n ∈ N, j = 1, \dots , k_n\right\}$ is a triangular array that satisfies
>   the hypotheses of the Lindeberg-Feller central limit theorem. In particular, $E(X_{n,j}) = 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{k_n}E(X^2_{
> n,j} ) = 1.$
>   Show that the array is infinitesimal, that is,
>   $\lim_{n→∞}
> \max\{P(|X_{n,j} | > ε : j = 1, . . . , k_n\} = 0$
>   for every $ε > 0$. In particular, conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} k_n = +∞.$

My Try:

$$\{P(|X_{n,j} | > ε : j = 1, . . . , k_n\}=\Pi_{j=1}^{k_n} \{P(|X_{n,j} | > ε\}\leq \frac{1}{((\epsilon n)^2)^{k_n}} \Pi_{j=1}^{k_n}E(X^2_{
n,j} )$$ By the hypotheses I know that $E(X^2_{
n,j} )$'s are positive and strictly less than $1$. So, I understand why we must prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} k_n = +∞.$. But I am stuck how to prove it. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for all $j\in\left\{1,\dots,k_n\right\}$, 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\left\lvert X_{n,j}\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon  \right\}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb P\left\{ \left\lvert X_{n,j}\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon  \right\}\leqslant\frac 1{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{j=1}^n
\mathbb E\left[X_{n,j}^2 \mathbb 1\left\{\left\lvert X_{n,j}\right\rvert \gt \varepsilon  \right\}\right].$$